# macports install log?

Tags: macos, macports

Does Macports have an install log? I can't find the location that it installed something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The contents action displays the files that have been installed by a given port. Uninstalled ports cannot have their contents listed.
>
> ```
> %% port contents PORTNAME
> ```
>
> — http://guide.macports.org/chunked/using.html#using.port.contents